# How to properly iterate through a file using nested loops

Tags: python, loops

I'd like to read through a file until I reach a certain marker, in this example a line containing the string "item":

**file.txt**

```
data
data
data
<item1
  data foo
  data bar
>
otherdata
<item2
  data bar
>
otherdata
<item3
  data foo
>
otherdata
```

Once I reach "item" I would then like to read the sections of data contained in each item block, but I figured it would make the most sense to use another loop to process the data because I have to do the same processing a bunch of times. 
 What I don't know is if I should be using the same loop counter for the inner and outer loops like this:

```
with open("file.txt") as myFile:  
    for strLine in myFile:
        if "item" in strLine:
            for strLine in myFile: #using same counter as outer loop
                processitemdata()
                if ">" in strLine:
                    break
```

or a different one like this:

```
with open("file.txt") as myFile:  
    for strLine in myFile:
        if "item" in strLine:
            for x in myFile: #using different counter than outer loop
                processitemdata()
                if ">" in strLine:
                    break
```

So what's weird is that they both work whether I use the same loop counter (is that the correct name?) for the inner and outer loops, or a different counter for the nested loop.

Also, I wasn't sure how Python knew to advance to the next line of the file instead of start over, but I'm guessing there some kinda subsystem that updates a line counter every time I access a line from myFile?

It feels strange to be looping over a file object and then having a nested loop looping over that same file object as if it would somehow reset the line counter, but it obviously works as Python seems to keep track regardless of how many nested loops I use.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something inherently wrong or using poor style.  I do understand that using a while loop might make more sense for the inner loop, but this is the way I initially wrote and didn't feel like rewriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop are basically just saying

```
strLine = next(myFile)
```

over and over until `StopIteration` is raised.

Nesting the loops that way is fine. I'd usually use an extra line (the `continue`) to save an extra level of indentation.

```
with open("file.txt") as myFile:  
    for strLine in myFile:
        if "item" not in strLine:
            continue

        for strLine in myFile: #using same counter as outer loop
            processitemdata()        # Should you test for ">" first?
            if ">" in strLine:        
                break
```

Aside: Are you sure that "item" can't occur in any of the data lines?

Comment: `for strLine in myFile:` desugars more like `tmp = iter(myFile); while True: try: strLine = next(tmp); except StopIteration as e: break` (although not quite, because an `else:` clause will behave differently with `break`). The significant part is that you're missing the `iter()` call. Nesting the `for` means calling `iter()` twice. This happens to work on file IO but not necessarily on other iterable containers.

Comment: @ephemient, `iter` on a file just returns the file. I didn't want to overcomplicate the answer with a complete breakdown. Perhaps your comment suffices for people who wish to know more detail

Comment: @john Thanks for the info and I like the idea of the continue so it doesn't get crazy nested.  There's more code going in there so that might prove helpful.  In regards to your aside, I will be adding other sanity checks to make sure I'm looking at the correct data - this was a very oversimplified example.

Comment: @ephemient thanks for the breakdown.  While I don't completely understand the underlying systems, it's nice to get a glimpse into the workings under the hood :)

Comment: @Mike Sure, no problem. The difference isn't important in *this* case, but you'll get different behavior if you nest `for` loops with other things, such as lists.

Comment: @ephemient ok, that's good to know.  Now, if I wanted to use this on a list, what would I need to do differently?

Comment: @Mike, The second for loop would create a new iterator, so start at the top of the list again. You could get similar behaviour by first creating an iterator and then using the same iterator with each loop. eg `lineiter = iter(list(myfile))`